# Ambiguous type variable with HashMap

Tags: haskell

I recently starting to play with haskell and I came across a problem while using HashMap that can be illustrated by this toy example:

```
import Data.HashMap as HashMap

foo = HashMap.insert 42 53 HashMap.empty
```

Here is the error I get when I load my file in the interpreter or compile it:

```
Prelude List HashMap> :load TypeError.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TypeError.hs, interpreted )

TypeError.hs:3:22:
    Ambiguous type variable `k0' in the constraints:
      (Num k0) arising from the literal `42' at TypeError.hs:3:22-23
      (Ord k0) arising from a use of `insert' at TypeError.hs:3:7-20
      (Data.Hashable.Hashable k0)
        arising from a use of `insert' at TypeError.hs:3:7-20
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      foo :: Map k0 Integer (bound at TypeError.hs:3:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    In the first argument of `insert', namely `42'
    In the expression: insert 42 53 empty
    In an equation for `foo': foo = insert 42 53 empty
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude List HashMap>
```

However if I define the exact same function directly in the interpreter, I get no error:

```
Prelude List HashMap> let foo = HashMap.insert 42 53 HashMap.empty
Prelude List HashMap>
```

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that ghci uses extended default rules, while the compiler uses (by default) the [defaulting rules specified in the language report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4):

Ambiguities in the class Num are most common, so Haskell provides another way to resolve them—with a default declaration: default (t1 , … , tn) where n ≥ 0, and each ti must be a type for which Num ti holds. In situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type variable, v, is defaultable if:

- v appears only in constraints of the form C v, where C is a class, and
- at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, Num or a subclass of Num), and
- all of these classes are defined in the Prelude or a standard library

---

The relevant rule is that per the report defaulting is only done if all involved classes are defined in a standard library, but the `Hashable` constraint on the key involves a class that doesn't meet that requirement.

Thus the compiler rejects it, because it can't resolve the ambiguous type variable arising from the key, while ghci defaults it to `Integer`, since ghci also defaults if other classes are involved.